# How do appending to associative array with variables work

Tags: php, html

i'm doing this exercise to understand te concepts and syntax of php.The error i get is that the array is not being appended by a new entry from a text box, if i hard code the values the program works fine and prints the array values. but as soon as i put the variable it just assign a new value to the [0] index.
here is the code:

````
  <label for="Name">Student Name:
  <input type="text" name="StdName" placeholder="Your name">
  </label>
  <label for="Name">Grade:
  <input type="text" name="StdGrade" placeholder="Your Grade">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"value="submit">
</form>


<?php
  // Associative array new
  $studentName =  $_POST['StdName'];
  $studentGrade = $_POST['StdGrade'];
  $classGrades = Array();
  $classGrades['name'][] = $studentName;
  $classGrades['grade'][] = $studentGrade;
  echo "<br> <br> Your name is: $studentName and your grade is: $studentGrade <br> <br>";
    foreach($classGrades as $key=>$value){
  echo join($value,' <br>');
  }
?>```
````

Comment: Can you show the hardcoded version as well please ?:)

Comment: labels shouldn't have inputs in them. Where's your `isset()` test in PHP?

Comment: i don't know about isset() how do you do that???

Comment: Placing `input` elements inside labels is valid @StackSlave.

Comment: Glad my solution helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. You have separate `name` and `grade` arrays, so that's what you need to loop over:

```
foreach ($classGrades['name'] as $index => $name) {
    $grade = $classGrades['name'][$index];
    echo "$name<br>$grade<br>";
}
```

But it would be better if you didn't create separate array and kept the name and grade together in a single associative array:

```
$classGrades[] = ['name' => $studentName, 'grade' => $studentGrade];
```

Then your loop would look like:

```
foreach ($classGrades as $grade) {
    echo $grade['name'] . "<br>" . $grade['grade'] . "<br>";
}
```

If you want the variable to persist between form submissions, you need to use a session variable.

Put

```
<?php
session_start();
```

at the beginning of the script. Then use `$_SESSION['classGrades']` instead of `$classGrades`, and initialize it like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['classGrades'])) {
    $_SESSION['classGrades'] = array();
}
```

Comment: I tried your anwser but it got worse i only get the input boxes and button but no array output, when i print_r($classGrades); i get an Array() output in Html it should print Array(name [0] -> zayno etc etc)

Comment: I had a typo `$classgrades` instead of `$classGrades`

Comment: yes i got it but i'm still not happy, the array does not append to te existing one. when i input a name and grade i does show thhe array: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => robert [grade] => B+ ) ), but hen i input a second value it just replaces te first one: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => cryl [grade] => B- ) ) instead i want: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => cryl [grade] => B-  Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => robert [grade] => B+ ) )

Comment: Do you realize that variables don't persist between script executions? Every time you submit the form, it starts with an empty `$classGrades` array.

Comment: If you need something to persist, you need to use a session variable.

Comment: aahhhh... i tried googleing for some examples but i'm puzzeled... can you point me in the right direction?? should this work:<?php 

 // starting the session
 session_start();


 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['picturenum'] = $_POST['picturenum'];
 } 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to store your values, in some database.

Here is a simple start using a json file named `students.json` as database. That file will be created along your php file in the same folder, if not existing.

First you was missing the form elements and the method (by default it uses GET, thus this was not working).

Testing with `isset()` avoids populating the database with empty values, at page load or refreshs.

This is not very secure as such, you will have to work on that later on. Hint: What if a user insert a quote `'` or `"` in his name?

```
<form method="post">
  <label for="Name">Student Name:
  <input type="text" name="StdName" placeholder="Your name">
  </label>
  <label for="Name">Grade:
  <input type="text" name="StdGrade" placeholder="Your Grade">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"value="submit">
</form>


<?php
  if (!is_file("students.json")){
    file_put_contents("students.json", json_encode([]) );
  }

  $classGrades = json_decode(file_get_contents("students.json"),true);

  if (isset($_POST['StdName']) && isset($_POST['StdGrade'])){

    var_dump($classGrades);

    $studentName =  $_POST['StdName'];
    $studentGrade = $_POST['StdGrade'];
    $classGrades['name'][] = $studentName;
    $classGrades['grade'][] = $studentGrade;

    echo "<br> <br> Your name is: $studentName and your grade is: $studentGrade <br> <br>";
    file_put_contents("students.json",json_encode($classGrades));
  }

  echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Grade</th></tr>";
  for ($i = 0;$i < count($classGrades['name']);$i++){
    echo "<tr><td>".$classGrades['name'][$i] . "</td><td> " .$classGrades['grade'][$i] . "</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: hello NVRM, i was wondering what you could do to make he output like: name: zano grade: B-. right now it just puts one array after another like zano robert betulia B- C A+

Comment: Hello. I made an edit check it out. It uses a for loop instead, maybe easier to read. It create a basic html table instead. From there use css to make it nice. Happy coding!